# Replace each underscore with a X

Tags: java, regex, replaceall

Use Case :

**Input** : "___Test_String"

**Output**: "XXXTest_String"

I would want to replace all the starting underscores with X.
The catch being each underscore should be replaced with a respective X.

**Conditions**:

The string may or may not start with an underscore. If it does not start with an underscore, it stays as is.

I tried:

```
replaceAll("[_]","X")  = XXXTestXString - It replaced all the underscores.
replaceAll("^[_]+","X") = XTestXString - Replaced all the starting underscores with a single X.
replaceFirst("_","X") = X__Test_String - Just replaced the first underscore.
```

I know this is very easy to accomplish using a non-regex way, but I would want a regexp solution if possible.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your last call works fine, you just used replaceFirst rather than replaceAll.

Comment: Well no, using replaceAll("_","X") would replace underscores in between as well. And as mentioned above, thats not what I want.

Comment: I misread the post. The solution posted below should work well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using `replaceAll("\\G_", "X")`.

The `\G` matcher means "The end of the previous match", which of course implies "The beginning of the input" on the first match. See javadoc of [`Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#bounds). See also [Regular-Expressions.info](https://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html).

The regex will keep matching as long as there is an underscore immediately following the previous match. It will match one underscore at a time, so each underscore is individually replaced with an `X`.

Once it finds the first non-underscore, matching ends, so the embedded underscore between `t` and `S` will not be matched.